# different gridview within different tab layout

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, tabs

hye, i'm a newb at android programming so i need help with my project, i'm trying to create an app with 3 tabs which each tab contain different gridview,

this is my current main activity, which already containing navigationdrawer, and fragment, when you run the app, it will look like this pict http://i59.tinypic.com/9jopyc.jpg[/IMG]

thanks for anyone who helping.

```js
package id.WKKR.ktcafe;

import tabs.SlidingTabLayout;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;

@
SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MenuUtama extends ActionBarActivity {

  Toolbar toolbar;
  private ViewPager mPager;
  private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
  public DaftarMakanan foodList;
  GridView makananGrid;

  @
  Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_utama);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    NavDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.MyPager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyTabs);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabsText);
    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.brown));

    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_utama, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "This Is " + item.getTitle() + " Button",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.bill) {
      startActivity(new Intent(this, BillTagihanAnda.class));
    }

    if (id == R.id.pesanan) {
      startActivity(new Intent(this, DaftarPesananAnda.class));
    }

    if (id == R.id.callwaiter) {
      startActivity(new Intent(this, PanggilPelayan.class));
      finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int icon[] = {
      R.drawable.ic_food, R.drawable.ic_drink,
        R.drawable.ic_desserts
    };
    String[] tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
      tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

    }

    @
    Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);
      return myFragment;
    }

    @
    Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icon[position]);
      drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
      ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
      SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
      spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

      return spannableString;
    }

    @
    Override
    public int getCount() {
      return 3;
    }

  }

  public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView textView;

    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
      MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("position", position);
      myFragment.setArguments(args);
      return myFragment;
    }

    @
    Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container,
        false);
      textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
      Bundle bundle = getArguments();
      if (bundle != null) {
        textView.setText("The Page Selected is " + bundle.getInt("position"));
      }

      return layout;
    }

  }

  class Menus {
    int imageId;
    String menus;
    String menusPrices;

    Menus(int imageId, String menus, String menusPrices) {
      this.imageId = imageId;
      this.menus = menus;
      this.menusPrices = menusPrices;
    }
  }

}
```

and here's my main activity xml :

```js
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="id.WKKR.ktcafe.MenuUtama" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/MyPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="id.WKKR.ktcafe.NavDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_nav_drawer_fragment"
        yourapp:layout="@layout/activity_nav_drawer_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try define grid in fragment xml and load data into grid base on view pager selected item position.

Comment: how could i load data into grid base? should i create an adapter?